# Cannot find Symbol - Method ClassA(int int) error in Java

Tags: java, class, variables, object, symbols

I have the following class, let's call it `ClassA` and its constructor which takes two variables:

```
public class ClassA
{
    // instance variables
    private int varA; 
    private String varReference; 
    private int varB; 

    public ClassA(int varLimit, int refNum)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        varA = 0;
        varReference = "VariableID " + refNum;
        varB = varLimit;
    }    
}
```

I then have ClassB which will want to use the constructor in ClassA to make a ClassA object like so:

```
public class ClassB
{
    // instance variables
    private int varC; 

    public ClassB(int maxTextBooks)
    {
    // Initialize Variables here 
    }

    public ClassA makeClass()
    {           
        return ClassA(5,varC);        
    }
}
```

However, whenever I try and compile that code I get the following error message:

> Cannot find symbol - method ClassA(int,int)

Comment: `return new ClassA(5,varC);`

Answer (score 1):

because you missed "new"

```
public ClassA makeClass()
{           
    return new ClassA(5,varC);        
}
```

Instead your program searches for a method "ClassA" and fails, thus the error.